# Qt5.11.2, QSqlDatabase and MariaDB on iMAC

Tags: c++, database, qt, mariadb

I'm trying to connect to a MariaDB on my iMAC.  I know the database name, the user name and password to connect are correct.

I've installed Qt5.11.2 and I'm trying the following:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
db.setHostName("Simons-iMac.local");
db.setDatabaseName("timekpr");
db.setUserName("timekpr");
db.setPassword("timekpr");
bool ok = db.open();
```

I've pinged the hostname in a terminal and I see an IP address returned.

When I get to the open method it returns false.  Is there anything else I can do to get more information on why it might be failing?

The iMAC is running iOS Mojave version 10.14

[Edit] When I run this using the debugger I see in the Application Output pane:

```
    2018-10-04 15:46:27.868976+0100 SimonQtWidgets[21670:626041] [default] Unable to load Info.plist exceptions (eGPUOverrides)
    2018-10-04 15:46:30.472706+0100 SimonQtWidgets[21670:625982] QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
    2018-10-04 15:46:30.472764+0100 SimonQtWidgets[21670:625982] QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QPSQL QPSQL7
    2018-10-04 15:46:34.975324+0100 SimonQtWidgets[21670:625982] QSqlError("", "Driver not loaded", "Driver not loaded")
```

I don't understand what's going on, according to the second line QMYSQL is available.  But the error reported is driver not loaded???

If it helps:

```
Hardware Overview:

  Model Name:            iMac
  Model Identifier:      iMac17,1
  Processor Name:        Intel Core i7
  Processor Speed:       4 GHz
  Number of Processors:  1
  Total Number of Cores: 4
  L2 Cache (per Core):   256 KB
  L3 Cache:              8 MB
  Memory:                16 GB
  Boot ROM Version:      IM171.0157.B00
  SMC Version (system):  2.34f2
```

[Another Edit] After adding QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 to the run time environment I now see in the Application Output:

```
    2018-10-10 10:30:42.060973+0100 SimonQtWidgets[2001:286805] Got keys from plugin meta data ("QPSQL7", "QPSQL")
    2018-10-10 10:30:42.060985+0100 SimonQtWidgets[2001:286805] QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/Users/simonplatten/build-SimonQtWidgets-Desktop_Qt_5_11_2_clang_64bit-Debug/SimonQtWidgets.app/Contents/MacOS/sqldrivers" ...
    2018-10-10 10:30:42.063252+0100 SimonQtWidgets[2001:286805] Cannot load library /Users/simonplatten/Qt/5.11.2/clang_64/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.dylib: (dlopen(/Users/simonplatten/Qt/5.11.2/clang_64/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.dylib, 133): Library not loaded: /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.20.dylib
      Referenced from: /Users/simonplatten/Qt/5.11.2/clang_64/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.dylib
      Reason: image not found)
    2018-10-10 10:30:42.063276+0100 SimonQtWidgets[2001:286805] QLibraryPrivate::loadPlugin failed on "/Users/simonplatten/Qt/5.11.2/clang_64/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.dylib" : "Cannot load library /Users/simonplatten/Qt/5.11.2/clang_64/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.dylib: (dlopen(/Users/simonplatten/Qt/5.11.2/clang_64/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.dylib, 133): Library not loaded: /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.20.dylib\n  Referenced from: /Users/simonplatten/Qt/5.11.2/clang_64/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.dylib\n  Reason: image not found)"
    2018-10-10 10:30:42.063293+0100 SimonQtWidgets[2001:286805] QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
    2018-10-10 10:30:42.063465+0100 SimonQtWidgets[2001:286805] QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QPSQL QPSQL7
```

It appears that Qt is expecting mysql to be located in:

```
    /usr/local/mysql/
```

The installation I have isn't, I searched for mysql using:

```
    find / -name mysql
```

And found:

```
    /usr/local/bin/mysql
```

Also:

```
    /usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.1.17/bin/mysql
    /usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.1.17/include/mysql
    /usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.1.17/share/mysql
    /usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.2.6/bin/mysql
    /usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.2.6/include/mysql
    /usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.2.6/include/mysql/mysql
    /usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.2.6/.bottle/etc/init.d/mysql
    /usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.2.6/.bottle/etc/logrotate.d/mysql
    /usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.2.6/share/mysql
```

I also found this in share:

```
    lrwxr-xr-x    1 simonplatten  admin     36 10 Jun  2017 mysql -> ../Cellar/mariadb/10.2.6/share/mysql
```

Is there anyway alter where Qt looks for mysql ?

Comment: Qt could be failing to load the drivers

Comment: I thought QMYSQL is one of the supported built in drivers.

Comment: Use [`QSqlDatabase::lastError`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#lastError) method to recieve more informations about what is going wrong. Note: To recieve error's text, use [`db.lastError().text()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlerror.html#text)

Comment: Yes it ought to be but I have seen it fail before and had to manually install drivers and add to project path.

Comment: @Tom, how?  I found something online but the path suggested doesn't work for me.

Comment: Have you tried adding -I / -L flags to the .pro file?

Comment: @J.D. can you elaborate?  Where and on what?

Comment: I was thinking about something like `LIBS += -L/usr/Cellar/mariadb/...`

Comment: @J.D. thank you, I'll try it but still not sure exactly what I need to specify.

Comment: Well, you were asking for a way to tell Qt where to look for MySQL. Assuming that the problem stems from Qt not finding a shared library, you could try adding `LIBS += -L/usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.2.6/share -lmysql` to your .pro file. My assumption might be wrong.

Comment: @J.D. I'm not sure thats going to work, thats fine if it was a build problem with a statically linked library, this isn't, the problem is a runtime error, where it cannot locate a shared object library.

Comment: You might be correct. But please, give it a try.

Comment: If this does not work, you could also try the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variables.

Comment: I wish I could say it helped, I modified DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, adding "/usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.2.6/lib" to the path, cleaned and rebuilt, still the same.

Comment: I just looked for libmysqlclient.20.dylib on my system, it doesn't exist anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, this is how:

Manually create the required folder structure, from /usr/local:

```
    sudo mkdir mysql
    cd mysql
    sudo mkdir lib
    cd lib
```

Create a symbolic link to the required library:

```
    sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.dylib /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.20.dylib
```

This then highlighted another problem using the domain name to connect, I resolved this by using localhost.